# How has CAD influenced aircraft design in the last few decades?

Tags: aircraft-design

I know that computer aided design was used extensively when designing the Boeing 777, are there any other good examples of aircraft where CAD was essential in the design process?

Are there any major leaps forward in aircraft technology that would have been impossible without CAD?

Comment: This seems to be an extremely broad question. You might get better answers if you focus your question on something more precise.

Comment: "*aircraft technology that would have been impossible without CAD*", it depends on how you think of "impossible". Impossible is also (if not mostly) a matter of budget and time. Engineer wouldn't have been able to design aircraft that are possible to manufacture, maintain, and sell without the help of systems like Catia. It's not limited to the aircraft industry.

Comment: There is nothing being done with CAD today in aircraft design that cannot be done without CAD, as long as you have unlimited time and resources. :)

Comment: Are you referring specifically to CAD (drawing), or CAE (finite element analysis, computational fluid dynamics, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

We used CATIA extensively in the design of the F-22.  It helped all the supporting "ilities" also in their tasks.  Great tool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you tell us a bit more detail about this -- what do you mean about all the supporting (lia?)"ilities"? Also, I know that Catia is a FEA force analysis tool, but I don't know that much about the process of incorporating it (and a CFD simulation) into a real design team's workflow -- how do you get forces into it from CFD, for example?

Comment: CATIA, for us was a design tool. Supportablity, reliability, quality, etc.  We did the whole F-22 program with CATiA at GA, WA and TX.  That allowed the three separate sites to have things coordinated.  We also used Integrated Product Teams (IPTs) that had their designers and own stress support, weight, producibility, reliability, CFD, manufacturing, procurement, etc.  Their were IPTs for the armament, fuselage structure, electronics, electrical installation, ECS, cockpit, transparency, landing gear, wings, empennage, ejection seat, integrated avionic racks, fuel system, hydraulics, etc., etc.